# Redirect everything to index (with htaccess and without messing images)

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect everything to index page (like www.domain.com/anything) without messing up the css, img and js loading on this page?

Should this work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html
RewriteCond $1 !^(img|css|js|font)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

Where the [RewriteCond `-f`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) will match any regular file calls (which are negated with the `!`). So you can call those normally and anything else (incl 404) are sent to the index.

Comment: Better to use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` as well